# Play a frame of a Movieclip when MOUSE_OVER

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent, mouseover

I have a map with different countries. When i hover over one of the countries, i want it to play a certain frame of a movieclip. I've made a movieclip for each country, which has 2 frames. The 1. frame is just the picture of the country like it appears on the map. Frame 2 is the country with the name over it. The second frame contains a stop(); Here is my code:

```
rømskog.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);
halden.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);
askim.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);
rømskog.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,outer);
halden.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,outer);
askim.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,outer);

function mover(e:MouseEvent):void {
   gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function outer(e:MouseEvent):void {
   gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

I know this code is incorrect, but i'm struggling to solve the problem. My movieclip starts automatic also, as the name of the country is visiable from the start. If somebody could learn me in the easiest way possible i would be very happy!

Comment: Main timeline, correct. Do you want the movieclips? how, and in what fileformat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code will do `gotoAndPlay` on the main timeline. You need to make the country movie clips timeline go to the appropriate frame instead.

All you should need to do is modify your two function like this:

```
function mover(e:MouseEvent):void {
   //e.currentTarget is a reference to the object that was clicked.  To avoid a compiler warning, we tell flash it's a movie clip.
   MovieClip(e.currentTarget).gotoAndStop(2); //if you don't want to actually play the timeline, use gotoAndStop
}

function outer(e:MouseEvent):void {
   //since this code is in the main timeline, doing gotoAndPlay will apply to it, not the object clicked

   //so like above, we tell the current target of the event to gotoAndPlay
   MovieClip(e.currentTarget).gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!

I'm not sure if MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT is doing what i want. I want frame 2 to be hidden until i choose to put my mouse over it. now it is visiable until i put my mouse on it, and will blink if i move my mouse ontop of it

Comment: Do you have a `stop();` on frame 1 of your countries?  What do you mean by blink?  Make sure your countries have a good solid area for the mouse over,  create a transparent background to help define the mouse over area if you need to.

Comment: I managed to fix it, so my program works as intended. Thank you so much